# How to save Jupyter notebooks from GitHub

Tags: jupyter-notebook

When I download an `ipynb` file using the RAW button in GitHub it displays the text (json) in the browser.

Should I just copy this text into a file and name it `xxx.ipynb`? What's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

1. First click on Raw
2. Then, press ctrl+s to save it as .ipynb (Note that you'll have to manually type '.ipynb' after the file name to make this work, as files from GitHub are saved as text files as default.)
3. Open jupyter notebook
4. Go to location where you saved .ipynb file
5. Open file, you will see the code

Hope this helps

Comment: For some reason, this does not work for me. It still gets saved as json

Comment: This did not work either. It sill got downloaded as txt file for me.

Answer (score 6):

The following steps worked for me:

1. Click on Raw in git repository.
2. Save the file. The file was saved as *.ipynb.txt format for me.
3. Then, in the jupyter directory tree (not in local directory), I selected, removed the .txt at the end and renamed the file as *.ipynb.
   [image]
4. Finally I was able to run the file as jupyter notebook.
   [image]

Note that, when I tried to rename the *.txt file in local directory to *.ipynb, it did not work. This had to be renamed in directory in jupyter itself.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the Lifesaver Extension developed by me for both

- Chrome
- Firefox

The project is open-sourced [here](https://github.com/iArunava/NoteBook-Buddy).

The extension not only opens github hosted notebooks in Colab but also in nbviewer!

And you can open the github repo from Colab and nbviewer
And go to nbviewer from Colab and github
Works all 3 ways!!

A new feature of opening new notebooks in one-click is already developed in the master branch, just need to push it to the extension platforms :)

[Firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/notebook-buddy/)

[Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/notebook-buddy/kmhoiofjdpbiodaggadcibdkicfgplcl)

Comment: Used it on google chrome and it works flawlessly with colab and binder.

Answer (score 2):

True to 2020:

- Click Download [image]
- Wait for JSON to finish loding in your browser
- Ctrl S (save as .txt file)
- remove .txt extension
- Run locally

Answer (score 0):

I saved the file following the instructions from this post. My destination however was a folder on google drive. I opened google drive on my browser and located the file. From there, I renamed the name of my file by just removing the txt extension, leaving the ipynb extension. That worked for me.